# Converting Month name to full date pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

My df is like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date data':['actual september 2019', 'September'],
                   'Date':['2019.12','2019.12']})
```

I would like to create a new columne and if `df['Date data']` is `'September'` I would like to write `df['new_column'] = '2019.09'`

the expected output is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date data':['actual september 2019', 'September'],
                   'Date':['2019.12','2019.12'], 'New_column':['2019.12','2019.09']})
```

i created a variable

`month = ('April', 'December', 'February', 'January', 'July-August', 'June', 'March', 'May', 'November', ' October', 'September')`

and

`df.loc[df['Date data'].isin(month) , 'new_col'] = '2019.9`

Comment: It's unclear what is the input and the expected output. Assuming "Date data" is the input and "Date" the output, how do you chose the year?

Comment: I editted the question and added the expected example output

Comment: Do you mean you want a manual: `df.loc[df['Date data'].eq('September'), 'New_column'] = '2019.09'` or `df['New_column'] = np.where(df['Date data'].eq('September'), '2019.09', df['Date'])`?

Comment: I created a variable `month = ('April', 'December', 'February', 'January', 'July-August', 'June', 'March', 'May', 'November', ' October', 'September')` and trying to say df.loc[df['Month'].isin(month) , 'new_col'] = '2019.9 or other

Comment: Can you provide a more complex example?

Comment: OK, let's start over. You need to explain the logic that you try to achieve. I imagine you do not want to assign 2019.09 for any month?

Comment: What i want something like this `df['New_column'] = np.where(df['Date data'].eq('September'), '2019.09', df['Date'])` but instead '2019.09' i would like to have if it is september it is  2019.09 if it is april new column 2019.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
from calendar import month_name

mapper = {m.lower(): f'{i:02d}' for i,m in enumerate(month_name)}

df['New_column'] = (df['Date data'].str.lower()
                    .map(mapper)
                    .radd('2019.')
                    .fillna(df['Date'])
                    )
```

example:

```
               Date data     Date New_column
0  actual september 2019  2019.12    2019.12
1              September  2019.12    2019.09
2                  ApRil  2019.12    2019.04
```

Comment: Is it possible to revise the code ```df['New_column'] = (df['Date data'].str.lower()
                    .map(mapper)
                    .radd('2019.', '2022.')
                    .fillna(df['Date'])
                    )```

Comment: `radd('2019.', '2022.')` wouldn't work. How do you choose how to apply 2019 or 2022?

Comment: in fact in my original df, the column Date has 422k rows and half 2019 and half 2022

Comment: Then you need an additional logic, maybe a `groupby`. Or extract the year. In any case more details are needed.

Comment: extracting year won't help me, i need the years. additional logic can be but how, i am really not in your level of python that's why need your help here. thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to create a new column similar to `Date`. Rows where `Date data` is equal to a month I change the column number in `Date` and put it in the new column.

If all months start with a capital letter (easy):

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
df['New_column'] = df['Date']
for nr, month in enumerate(months):
    df.loc[df['Date data'].eq(month), 'New_column'] = df['Date'].str[:5] + str(nr + 1).zfill(2)
```

If months can be with or without capital letter, use `.lower()`:

```
months = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december']
df['New_column'] = df['Date']
for nr, month in months:
    df.loc[df['Date data'].str.lower().eq(month), 'New_column'] = df['Date'].str[:5] + str(nr + 1).zfill(2)
```

Output:

```
               Date data     Date New_column
0  actual september 2019  2019.12    2019.12
1              September  2019.12    2019.09
```

Comment: @GorkemTunc why did you remove the 'accept as answer'?

Comment: i misunderstood, than after i managed to apply the code to my original df. But now the problem is I have `2019.12`` and `2022.05` in `df['Date']`, and it is giving not the exact output but a different one

Comment: Sorry @mozway's answer works perfect